# How to efficiently copy millions of rows from one table to another in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have two database tables. One contains hundreds of millions of records. Lets call that one `history`. The other one is calculated on daily basis and I want to copy all of its records into the `history` one.

What I did was to run:

`INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM daily`

And it did the trick for a while, but it started to get slower and slower as the number of records kept growing. Now I have around 2 million records that need to be copied from `daily` to `history` in single operation and it takes too long to complete.

Is there another, more efficient way of copying data from one table to another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you plan to keep history for long periods (many months), I suggest having a look at partitioning options - may be one partition for each day or week and so on. It does depend on the access patterns of you history table also (do you run queries that access data across dates? Do you do a lot of aggregations etc). Have a look at materialized views for storing aggregates/summaries.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like the only way to go. I'd need to partition the data by months and thus making reindexing (since index regeneration was a problem here) much faster.

Answer (score 21):

The problem was with indexes. The `history` table had 160M indexed rows. By running either `COPY FROM` or `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` it was taking a lot of time not to insert rows, but to update indexes. When i disabled indexes, it imported 3M rows in 10 seconds. Now i need to find faster way of reindexing the big table.

Comment: Do you even need indexes on a history table?

Comment: Add the index using the CONCURRENTLY keyword

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, did you copy it with the `COPY` command or with the insert command?

Answer (score 18):

Dump the table in csv format

```
COPY table TO '/tmp/table.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

use the COPY command which is far more efficient for large amounts of data.

```
COPY table FROM '/tmp/table.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

Check postgres docs at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html for more info

Comment: Its still running very, very slow... Perhaps it has to do something with having to rebuild such a huge index? There is 160 million rows in `history` table, and we're appending 3 more million rows.

Comment: Of you are fulling an empty table, or adding more rows than already exist, it is usually more efficient to drop non-clustered indexes and recreate them once the transfer is complete (unless there is active use of the table(s) at the time)

Comment: BTW, is this a one off operation or is it something you have to do regularly? If its on a regular basis i sugest that you create a trigger so you don't have to go through this ordeal every time.

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni - It has to be performed on daily basis at specific time (kinda taking snapshots in time).

Comment: @DavidSpillett - indeed! Dropping indexes makes import very fast (see my answer above), however, recreating indexes takes hours (since I have 160M rows in database)..

Comment: Do you think index fillfactor might help here?

Comment: NOTE: `binary` format will be the most efficient speed-wise for importing, exporting, and storage.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) tool, I might be efficient, as the following,

```
psql -h ${DAILY_HOST_IP} -p ${PG_PORT} ${DB_NAME} ${USER_NAME} -c "copy daily to stdout " | psql -h ${HISTORY_HOST_IP} -p ${PG_PORT} ${DB_NAME} ${USER_NAME}  -c "copy history from stdin"
```

Also you can write a shell script.

Comment: Great solution without intermediate file. Very fast too, I copied a 950 millions rows table in 1h20 (without indexes) between regular disk and network file system.

Comment: It's a real pity this can't be done directly from one table to another.

Comment: This command will not be fast if the server and the client machine is not the same machine! The first command needs to get all the data from server to client's stdout. Then the pipe copies it to server again. Too much network transfer will make it horribly slow.

Answer (score 3):

This is of course not an exact answer to your question, but if you don't need to access the `history` table, you can as well generate an SQL dump:

```
pg_dump -h host -p port -w -U user db > dump.sql
```

Then one could use a tool like `git` to calculate the difference and store this efficiently.

```
git add dump.sql
git commit -m "temp dump"
git gc --aggressive
```

This is useful because most parts in a database, will not change every day. Instead of storing an entire copy for every day, one can store the difference between two days.

You can use a `crontab` job such that the dump is processed every day.